# Hibernate Reverse Engineering Exception

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jdbc

I am trying to reverse engineer a SQL Server database by following a tutorial (actually I tried a few but here is one):
[How to generate Hibernate mapping files & annotation with Hibernate Tools](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-generate-code-with-hibernate-tools/)

The question is: what kind of project I have to choose? Does it have to be JPA project? If so, should/must I use EclipseLink?

Why I am asking is because I created a JPA-faceted project which used EclipseLink. I created the connection to the database, using sqljdbc driver, and the "ping" worked. However when I try to get an exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2005Dialect.registerColumnType(IJLjava/lang/String;)
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent the whole day trying to resolve this issue... and did learn a lot (although am still confused about JPA stuff a bit).

The issue is due to using following line in the "hibernate.cfg.xml" file:

```
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2005Dialect</property>
```

Changing the property to "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" solved the issue and exception disappeared.

Comment: trying to "reverse engineer" a database without being fluent in hibernate / JPA - configuration / setup is like trying to defeat a leviathan with a broken stick. If you actually want to accomplish something useful, you will need to start from the beginning and learn every basic aspect of Java + JPA + Hibernate.
You would've known that choosing the wrong dialect results in weird errors if you actually had SOME experience with the topic.
Never start from the very top, going from the base upwards is the way to go.

Comment: I appreciate your advice and the simile, but I have a very specific task and limited amount of time to do it. Also I believe it is easier to learn by solving some concrete problems rather then by just reading or reading and perhaps performing some semi-abstract examples.
I do agree however that I could spend a bit more time reading topics relevant to the task at hand... which I will do :)